# Webcrawler BeautifulSoup - how do I get titles from links without class tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

The site I am trying to gather data from is http://www.boxofficemojo.com/yearly/chart/?yr=2015&p=.htm. Right now I want to get all the titles of the movies on this page and later move onto the rest of the data (studio, etc.) and additional data inside each of the links. This is what I have so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen

def trade_spider(max_pages):
    page = 0
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = 'http://www.boxofficemojo.com/yearly/chart/?page=' + str(page) + '&view=releasedate&view2=domestic&yr=2015&p=.htm'
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
        for link in soup.findAll('a', {'div':'body'}):
            href = 'http://www.boxofficemojo.com' + link.get('href')
            title = link.string
            print title
            get_single_item_data(href)
        page += 1

def get_single_item_data(item_url):
    source_code = requests.get(item_url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
    for item_name in soup.findAll('section', {'id':'postingbody'}):
        print item_name.text

trade_spider(1)
```

I section I am having trouble with is

> for link in soup.findAll('a', {'div':'body'}):
>
> href = 'http://www.boxofficemojo.com' + link.get('href')

The issue is that on the site, there's no identifying class in which all the links are part of. The links just have an "< ahref > " tag.

How can I get all the titles of the links on this page?

Comment: Doesn't that call get all the links on the page?

Comment: Not sure, nothing is printing

Comment: When you print data from the web use `repr(data)`, you might have hold of a new line character `\n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way is using [`.select()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) method which accept CSS selector parameter :

```
for link in soup.select('td > b > font > a[href^=/movies/?]'):
    ......
    ......
```

**brief explanation about CSS selector being used :**

- `td > b` : find all `td` element, then from each `td` find direct child `b` element
- `> font` : from filtered `b` elements, find direct child `font` element
- `> a[href^=/movies/?]` : from filtered `font` elements, return direct child `a` element having `href` attribute value starts with `"/movies/?"`

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for not giving a full answer, but heres a clue.

I have a made up name for these problems in scraping.
When I use the `find()`, `find_all()` methods I call this `Abstract Identification` since you could get random data when tag class/id names are not data oriented.

Then theres `Nested Identification`. That's when you have to find data not using the `find()`, `find_all()` methods, and instead literally crawl through a nest of tags. This requires more proficiency in `BeautifulSoup`.

Nested Identification is a longer proccess that's generally messy but is sometimes the only solution.

So how to do it? When you have hold of a `<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>` object you can locate tags that are stored as attributes of the tag object.

```
from bs4 import element, BeautifulSoup as BS

html = '' +\
'<body>' +\
    '<h3>' +\
        '<p>Some text to scrape</p>' +\
        '<p>Some text NOT to scrape</p>' +\
    '</h3>' +\
    '\n\n' +\
    '<strong>' +\
        '<p>Some more text to scrape</p>' +\
        '\n\n' +\
        '<a href="www.example.com/some-url/you/find/important/">Some Important Link</a>' +\
    '</strong>' +\
'</body>'



soup = BS(html)

# Starting point to extract a link
h3_tag = soup.find('h3') # finds the first h3 tag in the soup object

child_of_h3__p = h3_tag.p # locates the first p tag in the h3 tag

# climbing in the nest
child_of_h3__forbidden_p = h3_tag.p.next_sibling 
# or
#child_of_h3__forbidden_p = child_of_h3__p.next_sibling


# sometimes `.next_sibling` will yield '' or '\n', think of this element as a 
# tag separator in which case you need to continue using `.next_sibling`
# to get past the separator and onto the tag.

# Grab the tag below the h3 tag, which is the strong tag
# we need to go up 1 tag, and down 2 from our current object.
# (down 2 so we skip the tag_seperator)
tag_below_h3 = child_of_h3__p.parent.next_sibling.next_sibling


# Heres 3 different ways to get to the link tag using Nested Identification

# 1.) getting a list of childern from our object
childern_tags = tag_below_h3.contents

p_tag = childern_tags[0]
tag_separator = childern_tags[1]
a_tag = childern_tags[2] # or childrent_tags[-1] to get the last tag

print (a_tag)
print '1.) We Found the link: %s' % a_tag['href']


# 2.) Theres only 1 <a> tag, so we can just grab it directly
a_href = tag_below_h3.a['href']

print '\n2.) We Found the link: %s' % a_href


# 3.) using next_sibling to crawl
tag_separator = tag_below_h3.p.next_sibling
a_tag = tag_below_h3.p.next_sibling.next_sibling # or tag_separator.next_sibling

print '\n3.) We Found the link: %s' % a_tag['href']
print '\nWe also found a tag seperator: %s' % repr(tag_separator)

# our tag seperator is a NavigableString.
if type(tag_separator) == element.NavigableString:
    print '\nNavigableString\'s  are usually plain text that reside inside a tag.'
    print 'In this case however it is a tag seperator.\n'
```

Now If I remember right, accessing a certain tag or a tag seperator, will change the object from a `Tag` to a `NavigableString` in which case you need to pass it through `BeautifulSoup` to be able to use methods such as `find()`. To check for this you can do as so.

```
from bs4 import element, BeautifulSoup
# ... Do some beautiful soup data mining
# reach a NavigableString object
if type(formerly_a_tag_obj) == element.NavigableString:
    formerly_a_tag_obj = BeautifulSoup(formerly_a_tag_obj) # is now a soup
```